# How to recover ether from Parity wallet with private key?

Tags: ether, parity, accounts, myetherwallet, parity-wallet

Given the multi-sig wallet vulnerability with Parity, I am curious why Parity wallet users are unable to access their ether using the private key provided by Parity?

Perhaps my understanding of the vulnerability (and the way Parity works, for that matter) is incomplete, but my assumption was that if you received ether to an Ethereum address that Parity created for you, you should be able to access that address using the private key. One could just use MyEtherWallet with their private key to access the funds in an address.

According to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23963/parity-export-private-key-for-cold-storage), it appears Parity does not provide you with the actual private key and you would've had to use the `ethkey generate random` command to "export" the private keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no private key for the multisig wallets- they are contracts.

Contract addresses are determined by hashing the address of the creator of the contract with a nonce, they are not the hash of an ecdsa public key.

The multisig wallet was a contract with associated code that allowed authorized accounts to withdraw the funds, but then the code was deleted, leaving the funds with no means of withdrawal.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize a wallet in Parity is just a contract (documentation from github [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Accounts%2C-Wallets%2C-Vaults)).

Comment: Also relevant: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/212/whats-the-difference-between-accounts-and-wallets-in-mist